# Using formatter in appendRow easy-ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

I'm trying to write an appendRow command in datagrid which has a formatter for every field.
This is my current code:

```
    $('#tt').datagrid('appendRow',
                                    {
                                       name: message.name
                                    })
```

message is json array. This code works properly but when I add formatter to it, formatter doesn't work.

```
<script>
        function formatPrice(val,row){

            return '<span style="color:red;">('+val+')</span>';

        }
    </script>



 $('#tt').datagrid('appendRow',
                                    {
                                       name: message.name,
                                       formatter: formatPrice
                                    })
```

Note: I've already tried this code to add a formatter with:

```
$('#tt').datagrid('appendRow',
                                        {
                                           field: 'message.name'

                                        })
```

but the upper code only appends an empty row at the end of the datagrid.

how can I use a formatter for field name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem by adding the formatter to the row of the table which I am appending a row to:

```
<table style="text-align: center" id="tt"  class="easyui-datagrid"
 url="getusers" 
 rownumbers="true" pagination="true">
<thead style="text-align: center">
    <tr style="text-align: center">
        <th field="name" formatter="formatPrice">NAME</th>
        <th field="age" >AGE</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

So when I add this code the rows appended, will be in format of formatPrice function:

```
$('#tt').datagrid('appendRow',
                                        {
                                           field: 'message.name'

                                        })
```